# How to get available dates with reservations?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a system which lets users reserve a item, let's say a laptop..

My table looks like this:

```
Table 'items'
id int(20) PK auto_increment
type int(20) FK(types.id)
name varchar(200)

Table 'types'
id int(20) PK auto_increment
name varchar(200)

Table 'reservations'
id int(20) PK auto_increment
user int(20) FK(users.id)
startDate datetime
endDate datetime
```

Lets say I have 1 type (laptops) and 3 laptops all with the same specs, and a user just wants to reserve **one** laptop. How would I get all **available** dates for just a laptop ?

I dont mind how this is reached, either via PHP or MySQL, I just intend on letting users have a list with available dates for the given type of item..

Comment: you may want to add the `item` in the table `'reservations'`, otherwise you won't be able to see which item is reserved.

Comment: Yes, that's obviously the case, tho that's not the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your reservation form prompts for $start and $end date/times for the reservation, this query will tell which laptops are available throughout the period specified by those two dates:

```
SELECT items.id, items.name
FROM items
LEFT JOIN types ON items.type = types.id
LEFT JOIN reservations ON reservations.item_id = items.id
WHERE (((reservations.endDate NOT between $start AND $end) and
      (reservations.startDate NOT between $start AND $end)) or
      (reservations.id IS NULL)) and
      (types.id = $laptop_type_id)
```

The first two `between` clauses will find any laptops whose start/end dates do not fall withing the requested start/end dates - e.g. they're reserved, but are available in the specified time range. The null check will find any laptops that not reserved at all. And the types.id check restricts the search to only laptops.

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for.. Even though it's a sort-of decent alternative.. 

What I do want is:

User tells us he wants a laptop, then he gets a list of available periods in where he can reserve a laptop..

Comment: Databases can't create data from nothing. Either you start with a list of periods and mark them in use (presenting only available ones), or you start with a list of in-use periods and eliminate ones that don't work.

Comment: Kind of was afraid for that, seems like I'll have to deal with it!